# CNN with sequence of images

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I would like to find out if there any papers that deals with handling a sequence of images that are not time dependent. Basically, a set of images would belong to a single class. However, existing CNN would be dealing with only a single image or with RCNN they also deal with a single image or those with temporal images.

I did think of concatentating all the pictures into one large picture but i feel it might not be exactly sensible. Does anyone have any recommendations.

Basically

I am trying to classify some object status based on the different images taken from multiple directions